# IOS Audio Player Mute Toggle & Audio Session for IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6

How to Mute Audio Player in ios ? Also mute when home button is pressed? And also how to set the Audio Session for ios?

Comment: mute audio player? Do you want some silent sound while audio player is playing? or you want to pause/play audio player..please make it clear.so,we can answer it further.

Answer (score 0):

**for mute**

```
[timeraudioPlayer setVolume:0.0];
```

**For Audio Session**

```
  AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *err = nil;
    [audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
    if(err)
    {
        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        return;
    }
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
    err = nil;
    if(err){
        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Is this useful to you?